# Rand sort on searchCriteria getItems

Tags: magento2, search-criteria

Is it possible to have a random sort when searching with repositories? Checked dev docs and unsure. Not found much elsewhere.

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/searching-with-repositories.html#sorting

```
use Magento\Framework\Api\FilterBuilder;
use Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaBuilder;
use Magento\Framework\Api\SortOrder;
use Magento\Framework\Api\SortOrderFactory;
```

```php
$this->searchCriteriaBuilder->addFilter(MessageInterface::STATUS, [Data::ENABLED], 'eq');
$randomSort = $this->sortOrderFactory
    ->create()
    ->setField(MessageInterface::SORT)
    ->setDirection(SortOrder::SORT_ASC); // random sort here
$this->searchCriteriaBuilder->setSortOrders([$randomSort]);
$searchCriteria = $this->searchCriteriaBuilder->create();
return $this->messageRepositoryInterface->getList($searchCriteria)->getItems();
```

Comment: Personally I think this is a missing feature - I've raised a git issue - see what happens https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/28315

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got a solution.

```php
$result = $this->messageRepositoryInterface->getList($searchCriteria)->getItems();
if ($group->getSortby() == Data::RANDOM) {
    shuffle($result);
    return $result;
}
return $result;
```

Comment: Only issue remains is that when a limit is introduced i.e. fetch only 1 record - it always randomly selects the same record - so not true `RAND()` but good enough for now

Answer (score 0):

You can use the built-in method `array_rand` to get either SORT_ASC or SORT_DESC. Something like this:

```
$this->searchCriteriaBuilder->addFilter(MessageInterface::STATUS, [Data::ENABLED], 'eq');

$directions = [SortOrder::SORT_ASC, SortOrder::SORT_DESC];
$randomDirection = $directions[array_rand($directions)];

$randomSort = $this->sortOrderFactory
    ->create()
    ->setField(MessageInterface::SORT)
    ->setDirection(randomDirection); // random sort here
$this->searchCriteriaBuilder->setSortOrders([$randomSort]);
$searchCriteria = $this->searchCriteriaBuilder->create();
return $this->messageRepositoryInterface->getList($searchCriteria)->getItems();
```

Comment: Good suggestion however I meant MySQL random sort eg `ORDER BY RAND()`

Comment: You can't use ORDER BY RAND() like that as SortOrder class validate the Direction to be either ASC or DESC. See the validation in \Magento\Framework\Api\SortOrder::validateDirectionIsAscOrDesc

I think you might want to switch to use MessageRepositoryCollection so you can use ORDER BY RAND()

Comment: Have you got an example on what a RepositoryCollection might look like?

Comment: Sorry, it is just my guess. I haven't used it before so I can't tell. Why can't you use array_rand() in PHP for it?

Comment: That would randomly sort in either direction. Whereas Mysql `RAND()` is a random sort

Answer (score 0):

Missing feature but very difficult to implement

https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/28315